# How to pass tuple elements to callable in C++

Tags: c++, tuples

How do I pass the elements of a tuple as arguments to *any* callable in C++? `std::apply` works only when the callable's arguments exactly match those of the tuple's.

For instance:

```
struct Foo {
   template<typename... Ts>
   Foo(std::string s, Ts&&... ts) {}
}

int main() {
   auto tup = std::make_tuple(5, 5.5f, 100000l);
}
```

In the code above, how would I make a `Foo` object by passing into its constructor some string value followed by the values stored in `tup`?

Comment: The solution for approximately 70% of C++ problems: [wrap it in a lambda](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c781951aab4e5120).

Comment: @MilesBudnek Maybe 30%. The 70% solution is `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can specify template arguments, thereby choosing the overload; or, you might do a simple forwarding lambda:

```
Foo f = std::apply([&](auto&&... args){ return Foo("", std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);}, tup);
```

Note that here I have added the first parameter as a string; an int is not accepted by `Foo` there.